# AngularJS routing /profile redirects to /profile/register when not logged in, browser history saves both routes

Tags: angularjs, redirect, angular-ui, angularjs-service, angularjs-routing

I'm facing a problem don't know how to solve. I would like to get some light here.

Given an AngularJS application that routes using the standard $routerProvider, and considering the fact that whenever an end user tries to access a private area he gets redirected to the register area, happens the following:

1. User just landed onto de application (didn't get logged in).
2. User goes to /profile
3. The application checks whether there is session info in the client or not.
4. The application redirects to /profile/register
5. User clicks on "Back" button of the browser and goes to /profile.
6. (Next step is number 3 again and again).

This happens because each time the application redirects using the $routerProvider, it pushes all routes in the browser history.

> My question is, how can I jump the failed /profile access over the browser history? How can I tell the browser do not save this route under given conditions
>   like the user is logged in?

FAQ regarding history: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Supposing you're using the `$location` built-in service to redirect, you can use [`$location.replace()`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$location#replace) to replace the current history entry:

```
if (notLoggedIn) {
    $location.url( "/profile/register" );
    $location.replace();
}
```

Note that this will apply to current digest only, as noted in the API docs.